# Is there a way to use scripts on elements which are included after the page is loaded?

Tags: javascript, jquery

When an element is clicked, I load new elements with the same class into the page.

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".myClass").click(function(){
            --load_new_elements with class="myClass"--
        });
    });
```

Is it possible to make the script working for new loaded elements as well - or must I each time load a new script for the newly created elements?

Comment: Sounds like a case for https://javascript.info/event-delegation

Comment: @vsemozhebuty Thank you, that is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

So you want to use a delegate event handler. See below.

$("div#container").on('click', 'button.alert', function() {
alert(1);
});

This will bind the click to new events as well.